# QGIS LRS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, linear-referencing

I am new to QGIS. I have recently installed LRS plugin. I can't seem to activate OK button in calibration. I have shapefile with well define line string.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your spatial reference set for the project/shape file? I'm not 100% sure on that plugin but if your spatial reference isn't set it's a common cause for inactivity... also you might need to be editing and/or highlight the layer (make it the primary layer). Make sure the plugin matches your QGIS install version, there's so many versions and sometimes the old tools are not yet supported by the new QGIS version. That covers the basics. Let me know if any of those help.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you give some more information? What version of QGIS, and what spatial references are set for your data?